# Unable to open sdk manager in android studio

Tags: android

I am unable to open android sdk manager in android studio i recently downloaded this.when i click this it shows me a pop up :
Cannot launch SDK manager.
Output:

'"C:\Users\suraj\AppData\Local\Android\ANDROI~2\sdk\tools\lib\find_java.exe" -s' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

ERROR: No suitable Java found. In order to properly use the Android Developer
Tools, you need a suitable version of Java JDK installed on your system.
We recommend that you install the JDK version of JavaSE, available here:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

If you already have Java installed, you can define the JAVA_HOME environment
variable in Control Panel / System / Avanced System Settings to point to the
JDK folder.

You can find the complete Android SDK requirements here:
  http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

so can anyone help me .!!! how to overcome this problem 
I am using windows 7 os

Comment: Did you install the JDK for your system?

Comment: Do you have Java Developer Kit (JDK) installed in your PC?

Comment: yes .. i use to code in eclipse before for android apps.. but now i turned to AS

Comment: But AS have some requirements, make Sure its JDK not JDE which is installed, and set the JAVA_HOME var in the Win7 System properties

Comment: i also did env variable setup.. but unable to get

Comment: Whats the path you added ?

Comment: C:\Program Files\JAVA\jdk1.7.0_21\bin.java.exe    is it right

Comment: Can you check in console window if command "java" and "javac" are found?! Also rightclick on your project folder ->open module settings, and check the JDK location path

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your environment vars JDK_HOME and JAVA_HOME are set properly to the installed JDK package.
AS requires oracle JDK, try to use the latest for your system.

Edit:
Check if "java" and "javac" are known as commands in console

Also check if the path to JDK is set in project properties:
Right click on project folder -> Open Module settings

Finally try to use / for the envi path instead of \ which usually is used in windows

Comment: can't open console::: ExecutionException: Can't open terminal session:java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY: java.io.IOException: Couldn't create PTY  @nouseforname

Comment: I meant a normal windows command line window (dos windows). If the commands are not known, the env var are not ok. Also take care the other options. otherwhise help is very difficult

Answer (score 0):

I have found a problem with the Android Studio studio.bat file 
and here it is

```
    ::------------------------------------------------------
    :: Locate a JDK installation directory which will be used to run the IDE.
    :: Try (in order): ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK, ..\jre, JDK_HOME, JAVA_HOME.
    :: ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    IF EXIST "%ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK%" SET JDK=%ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK%
    IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
    IF EXIST "%~dp0\..\jre" SET JDK=%~dp0\..\jre
    IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
    IF EXIST "%JDK_HOME%" SET JDK=%JDK_HOME%
    IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
    IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" SET JDK=%JAVA_HOME%
    IF "%JDK%" == "" GOTO error
```

Do you get the problem in the last 2 lines of code?
It seems that if your environmental variable is %JAVA_HOME% the batch file will GOTO error and an error message will be displayed and that's it NO ANDROID STUDIO FOR YOU, even though %JAVA_HOME% contains a valid path but if the environmental variable is something like %ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK% like mine is because I created it myself then it will work

---

#### PROPOSED SOLUTIONS

(1) Edit the batch file
Where you see this
`IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" SET JDK=%JAVA_HOME%
IF "%JDK%" == "" GOTO error` 
Change it to this
`IF EXIST "%JAVA_HOME%" SET JDK=%JAVA_HOME%
IF NOT "%JDK%" == "" GOTO jdk
IF "%JDK%" == "" GOTO error` 
(2) Create an environmental variable named %ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK%
as shown here
https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500